# TCP send data not in real time

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, arduino, ethernet

A few weeks ago I had opened a discussion about the communication between PC and Arduino through TCP packets (here the discussion: [Issues with TCP on Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350333/issues-with-tcp-on-arduino)).
I solved all the communication problems, but now I'm facing another problem: the TCP packets are not sent in real-time.
Between a package and another one spends a fraction of a second that slows down the process. I would like an application that receives a continuous flow of data and I thought that simple TCP packets could be sent (and received) instantly. But it is not like that.

This is the PC part code: it reads a text file and sends some characters read in each line. The process ends when all the lines have been read.

```
int send_data(){
   WSADATA wsa;
   SOCKET s;
   struct sockaddr_in server;

   if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0){
       printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
       return 0;
   }


   //Create a socket
   if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET){
       printf("Error: %d" , WSAGetLastError());
   }
   else
       printf("Socket created.\n");


   server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.144"); //Arduino IP
   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server.sin_port = htons( 1456 ); //Listen Port 

   if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0){
       printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
       return 0;
   }

   printf("Connected");


   char line[200];
   FILE *fp;
   if ((fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\...\\file.txt","r")) == NULL){
       printf("\nAn error occured opening file.");
       exit(-1);
   }


   while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
        char send_character[8];

        /*
        [...parsing character...]

        send_character[0]= ?
        send_character[1]= ?
        send_character[2]= ?
        send_character[3]= ?
        send_character[4]= ?
        send_character[5]= ?
        send_character[6]= ?
        send_character[7]= ?

        */


        if( send(s , send_character , 8 , 0) < 0){
            printf("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }

   }


   printf("\n\nData sent.");

   //Closing socket:
   if(closesocket(s)==SOCKET_ERROR) {
       wprintf(L"Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
       WSACleanup();
       return 0;
   }

   WSACleanup();
   return 1;
}
```

Can you tell me what am I wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: The slowness could be likely due to hardware limitations in your arduino device

Comment: `if( send(s , send_character , 8 , 0) < 0){` -->> check the return value. Also: look up `Nagle's algorithm`

Comment: Google: `TCP_NODELAY`

Comment: TCP is not a real-time protocol.

Comment: @wildplasser thank you! With TCP_NODELAY the situation has definitely improved (it is almost in real-time).
I added the setsock(_,_,TCP_NODELAY,_,_) line after the socket was created.
Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Yes: **check the return value** you get from send() or read(). It could be anything between -1 and 8, inclusive.

Comment: You can try to optimize rest of your code apart from socket part eg If the file you read is small enough cache it in memory, Do you send frequently if yes, dont create and close socket each time, just create once reuse same next time

Comment: @wildplasser I get always 8 as value.
Pras thank you!

Comment: in the posted code, there are several places where an error message is being sent to `stdout`.   Such error messages should be sent to `stderr`  Suggest using `fprintf( stderr, "...\n" );`   ALSO, when an error has occurred, the function should exit with some error code (usually -1) .  Returning 0 (usually) means success

Comment: the posted code is only sending 8 bytes on each cycle.  But the call to `fgets()` may have read upto 200 bytes,  Any particular reason to limit the amount of data sent each cycle?  Any particular reason to not send the rest of the data from each line in the input file?

Comment: only sending 8 bytes at a time results in the data being 'swamped' by the TCP overhead.  Suggest sending all the bytes read by each call to `fgets()` as a single block.  (this plan could begin to break down if the blocks were some 1600 bytes